# Excel - Create a Unit Conversion sheet - Multiple links

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a Unit conversion sheet in excel, but I am looking to have it linked both ways.

As an example,

```
A1 = 1 (value in metres)
B1 = A1*39.7 (value in inches)
C1 = B1/12 (value in feet).....and so on
```

In the above example, if I change value of A1 = 2, the cells B1 and C1 will change accordingly. But how can I develop a sheet, where I can change any value in B1 or C1, and the rest of the cells change automatically? Meaning I input C1 = 1 feet, it should automatically update my cell A1 = 0.30 (metres) and B1 = 12 (inches), which are the corresponding values for 1 feet.

Comment: You can't do a two-way link using formulas: you'll need to use VBA and look at something like the `worksheet_change` event.

Comment: A cell can either contain a formula or a value. You will need VBA to achieve what you want - using the `worksheet_change`-event and coding the calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Application.Intersect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iVal As Single
    Const TAB_RNG = "A2:C5" ' Modify as needed
    Const M2IN = 39.7
    Const IN2FT = 1 / 12
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(TAB_RNG)) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Select Case .Column
                Case Is = 1
                    iVal = .Value
                Case Is = 2
                    iVal = .Value / M2IN
                Case Is = 3
                    iVal = .Value / IN2FT / M2IN
                End Select
                Me.Cells(.Row, 1) = iVal
                Me.Cells(.Row, 2) = iVal * M2IN
                Me.Cells(.Row, 3) = iVal * M2IN * IN2FT
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My variant for 1 row of cells (A1:C1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Range("A1:C1")
        If cel.Address <> Target.Address And Not cel.HasFormula Then
            Select Case cel.Address(0, 0)
                Case "A1": cel.Formula = "=C1*12/39.7"
                Case "B1": cel.Formula = "=A1*39.7"
                Case "C1": cel.Formula = "=B1/12"
            End Select
        End If
    Next cel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: how can you change yours to 2 row of cells? The second row having a different formula (say for temperature degC and degF). I tried duplicating it and it did not work out.

Comment: It's kind of pointless. Do you want to use different formulas in one table? And are you sure you won't confuse them?
I wrote as you stated in the description. Update the description, I'll try to correct the proposal. Enter the formulas you want to use. Temperature conversion is two items, so a slightly different scheme.

Comment: I understand. So I created another question --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808105/excel-vba-unit-converter