# Excel VBA - Unit Converter

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel file to convert various Engineering Units. Based on another question I asked, I was suggested to go with a VBA code, and I am playing my hand at it.

However, the code I modified is not working as expected.

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("B3:G3")
    If cel.Address <> Target.Address And Not cel.HasFormula Then
        Select Case cel.Address(0, 0)
            Case "B3": cel.Formula = "=G3/304800"
            Case "C3": cel.Formula = "=B3/1000"
            Case "D3": cel.Formula = "=C3/10"
            Case "E3": cel.Formula = "=D3/100"
            Case "F3": cel.Formula = "=E3*39.3701"
            Case "G3": cel.Formula = "=F3/12"
            
        End Select
    End If
Next cel
```

This is to change the following excel cells.

[image: metres to inches]

I am also working on creating this for Temperature/ Pressure etc.

[image: Other Measurements]

Not sure, what I am missing in my code, and why I am getting wrong values even for simple measurements of metres to inches etc.

Comment: converting ft to micrometers requires multiplying by 304800 not dividing by 304800.

Comment: For converting distance, see my article [Convert and format imperial distance (feet and inches) with high precision](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31931/Convert-and-format-imperial-distance-feet-and-inches-with-high-precision.html?preview=TbXtlf8IKMA%3D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in the Sheet codepane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:G3")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
col = Target.Column
base = Target.Value * WorksheetFunction.Choose(col - 1, 0.000001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 2.54 / 100, 30.48 / 100)
For Each cel In Range("B3:G3")
      cel.Value = base * WorksheetFunction.Choose(cel.Column - 1, 1000000#, 1000#, 100#, 1, 100 / 2.54, 100 / 30.48)
Next cel
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hello - This does not work for something called Temperature.

Comment: This is a code for length. Obviously not works e.g. for yards. But following the concept you can create your own version for different measures. Copy the `If...End If` part below the `End If` statement. Adjust the range to the input/output range. Select a base measure and adjust the ratio in both `Choose` functions to it.( As can be seen they are reciprocal values.)  Check  and use  the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:G3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cel In Range("B3:G3")
        If cel.Address <> Target.Address And Not cel.HasFormula Then
            Select Case cel.Address(0, 0)
                Case "B3": cel.Formula = "=G3*304800"
                Case "C3": cel.Formula = "=B3/1000"
                Case "D3": cel.Formula = "=C3/10"
                Case "E3": cel.Formula = "=D3/100"
                Case "F3": cel.Formula = "=E3*39.3701"
                Case "G3": cel.Formula = "=F3/12"
            End Select
        End If
    Next cel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As already mentioned by @freeflow in comments there was an error in one formula.
If you want to have multiple conversions in one sheet, you need to check which row the `Target` is in and apply the conversions only to that row.

Comment: Could you please clarify more? Its really not working. I got an error on circular references. I even copy pasted your code, and its miscalculating um, mm etc.

Comment: Did you use `Application.EnableEvents=False` and `=True` by the end?

You can enter manually 1 constant into the row, you cannot enter formulas.